# Pattern for reading property list when the app launches, writing it when it closes

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a very small bit of data that I need to read into an array when my app launches using a property list. While the app is running, this data could change depending on what the user does. When the app closes, I then need to write the data back to the file.

From a high level point of view, I'm just wondering what is the best design pattern to do this? My first intuition is to simply declare an array in the `appDelegate` and access this array through an `appDelegate` instance when I need to. Then in the end,  he `applicationWillResignActive`: method to write the data back to the file.

However I've been told it's bad news to do declare a variable like this in the appDelegate, so I'm wondering if someone could tell me what the best methodology to accomplish this would be.

Comment: Where did you hear it was bad to declare a variable in the appDelegate?

Comment: I agree it is bad ... mainly because it will eventually lead to app delegates as long as the chinese wall. exceptions are okay but in general.. yes id say it is bad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what do your app want to do with the loaded data? If you need to access everywhere in your project, you can create a [singleton pattern](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/) (e.g SharedData class), get the static instance

```
e.g: [SharedData sharedInstance]
```

Whan you first get this instance, you can load the data from your property file.

And you should create an instance method e.g:

```
- (void) saveData;
```

And call it in the following method:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application{
   [[SharedData sharedInstance] saveData];
}
```

and

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{
   [[SharedData sharedInstance] saveData];
}
```

if you want to save when the Home button is pushed.
But the exact time when your data must be saved depends on the app workflow. It's better to save immediately after the operations which modify the stored data (maybe using a background thread).

Comment: Thanks for the great response. I mean this is just an array with 4 bools, should I just read it and write it everytime I need to access it?

Comment: This is a possible way, but on other, that you load it into an array,  when the app did finished launching, and if you modify one of the data, you modify the corresponding array element, and save all data (the full array) immediately. It a good practice in the case of really small amount of data.